# Multiprocessing with Pyglet opens a new window

Tags: python, multiprocessing, window, pyglet

I am making turn based game in python using Pyglet. The game has a player-vs-AI mode in which the bot calculates a move to play against the player. However, the function which calculates the bot's move takes around 3-5 seconds to run, blocking the game's UI. In order to get around this, I am running the bot's calculation on a second process using multiprocessing.Process. I got it to work well without blocking the UI, however every time I open the second process to run the function a new Pyglet window opens, then closes again when the process is closed. Is there any way to open a second process in a Pyglet program without a second window opening? Let me know if examples of my code is required, and I will try to come up with similar code to share. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by moving the initialization of the window inside of the main block